# Asus Refurnished Netbook First Time Charge

Tags: netbook

I just bought Asus Refurnished Netbook. For some reason it is taking an eternity for the first time charge. I have already plugged in for 3 hours and still it does not even open and shows LOW battery. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the battery is dead. Laptop batteries (usually LiIon rechargeables) only last for about three years under ideal conditions, and can die in a matter of months.

It's also possible that the recharging mechanism has failed, but much less likely. Your best bet is to buy a new battery (which you most likely need anyway). If it still fails to charge, make a warranty claim for your netbook.

For a new battery, [Anyone have any experience with bargain laptop batteries?](https://superuser.com/questions/152133/anyone-have-any-experience-with-bargain-laptop-batteries) might be interesting.